# Название подразделения министерства: прописная или строчная?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Нужно ли писать с прописной название «(У/у)правления связи (М/м)инистерства обороны», если речь идет о государственном учреждении США, но не в официальном тексте?

Comment: Как официально называется это управление в оригинале? Существует ли общепринятый перевод "Управление связи Министерства (при Министерстве) обороны"? В "википедии" упоминается только National Communications System (Нац. система связи), которая подчинена другому ведомству.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как в оригинале - это совсем не важно! У советских собственная гордость!

**[Вопрос № 289417](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=289417)**

> Уточните, пожалуйста, с прописной или строчной буквы стоит писать
>   названия министерств? Особенно иностранных. Например, министерство
>   обороны Украины?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Слово *министерство* пишется с большой буквы как первое слово
>   официального названия учреждения: *Министерство обороны Украины.* Если
>   полное официальное название не приводится, правильно написание
>   строчными, например: *в министерстве обороны пояснили...*

---

**[Вопрос № 300430](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20300430)**

> Слово "управление" в этом предложении "Обеспечение пожарной
>   безопасности – одна из важнейших стратегических задач, возложенных на
>   управление МЧС России по Архангельской области" надо писать с
>   заглавной буквы?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> В соответствии с законодательством в субъектах Российской Федерации -
>   главные управления МЧС России: *Главное управление МЧС России по
>   Архангельской области*.
>
> ---

Пишем не смущаясь:

*управления связи Министерства обороны США,*

а если США не тут же присутствует, а лишь в окрестностях, то

*управления связи министерства обороны*.

---

[Министерство обороны США (англ. Department of Defense — DoD или DOD, иногда употребляется название Defense Department)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%A1%D0%A8%D0%90) - у них вообще нет управлений связи, а есть:

> три военных отдела: Департамент армии США, Департамент военно-морского
>   флота США, Департамент военно-воздушных сил США. Кроме того,
>   министерству обороны подчиняются четыре национальных разведывательных
>   службы: Разведывательное управление министерства обороны США (DIA),
>   Агентство национальной безопасности США (NSA), Национальное агентство
>   геопространственной разведки (NGA) и Национальное управление
>   военно-космической разведки США (NRO).